# calling __init__ method in composition

Tags: python, inheritance, composition

I am trying to use composition in python but I wasn’t sure how to do it if I needed the `__init__` method from the other class. In other words, how do I do this `super(childClass, self).__init__(…)` with composition?

for example:

```
class Class*(object): 
    …. 

class ClassA(Class*):  
    def __init__(self, lst, ...):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__(...) 
    def meth1()
    def meth2()

class ClassB(Class*): 
    def __init__(self, name, lst=None, other=None)
        **here I want to use the __init__ method from ClassA**
        self.a = ClassA(..)
    def meth1():
        return self.a.meth1()
```

I hope this is clear. Thanks!

Comment: But this doesn't make sense. ClassB has no relation to ClassA; there is no composition *or* inheritance going on.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for the edits. I added more code, maybe it's clearer? please let me know. It's the first time I use composition.

Comment: After the edit, it's clear you're already calling `__init__` on `ClassA`.  When you say `self.a = ClassA(...)`, that calls `ClassA`'s `__init__` method.

Answer (score 4):

In a composition, your `ClassB` simply has a member that happens to be a `ClassA`, so, you *don't* invoke `ClassA`'s `__init__` method directly, you just instantiate it if you need to.

```
class ClassB(Class*):
    def __init__(self, name, lst=None, other=None):
        self.my_A = ClassA(lst, ...)
```

Comment: Shout out to Westerville. :)